# Leads view report

Tags: leads, reports-api

I Am struck with this report. Your help would be useful

Im in need of a report that i can run within the Leads record tab to see who from U.S who visited our website to download a product PDF, tradeshow attendee or who come to our website and specifically contacted about our products.

I need a solution for this and if you guyz need any info on the above question let me know and ill get bak to you

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Summary Report which would be available in Right bottom of the Lead Tab or you can create a list view with relevant conditions.